# Fail to Upsert Data on Cloudpage

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage

I'm trying to upsert a DE on my Cloudpage and have no idea where my mistakes are being made

My Cloudpage is something like this:

```
<script runat="server"> 
Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1"); 
try{ 
</script>
%%[
    Var @LinkParameter, @SubscriberKey, @CurrentClicks, @UpdateClicks, @ActualLink
    Set @SubscriberKey = _subscriberkey
    Set @LinkParameter = QueryParameter("Parameter")

    If @LinkParameter == "Collectors" THEN
        Set @CurrentClicks = Lookup("My DE - test", "Collectors", "CustomerID", @SubscriberKey)
        Set @UpdateClicks = Add(@CurrentClicks, 1)
        UpsertData("My DE - test", 1, "CustomerID", @SubscriberKey, "Collectors", @UpdateClicks)
        Set @ActualLink = "https://wwww.google.com"
        Redirect(@ActualLink)
    Endif
]%%
<script runat="server"> 
}catch(e){  
Write(Stringify(e)); 
} 
</script>
```

My DE: CustomerID relates to Subscribers on Subscriber Key

[image]

My Email content has this line: (1072 is the ID of the Cloudpage)

```
<a href="%%=CloudPagesURL(1072, 'Parameter', 'Collectors')=%%" title="" alias="" conversion="true" data-linkto="https://">Click my LINK</a>
```

ANd here is the result I got from try catch SSJS
 `{"message":"An error occurred when attempting to evaluate an Add function call. See inner exception for details.","description":"ExactTarget.OMM.FunctionExecutionException: An error occurred when attempting to evaluate an Add function call. See inner exception for details.\r\n Error Code: OMM_FUNC_EXEC_ERROR\r\n - from Jint --> \r\n\r\n --- inner exception 1---\r\n\r\nExactTarget.OMM.InvalidFunctionParameterException: Invalid value specified for function parameter.\r\n Function Name: add\r\n Parameter Name: Value1\r\n Parameter Ordinal: 1\r\n Parameter Type: Numeric\r\n Submitted Value: \r\n ClientID: 100004194\r\n JobID: 0\r\n ListID: 0\r\n BatchID: 0\r\n SubcriberID: 0\r\n Data Source Type: List\r\n Error Code: OMM_INVALID_FUNCT_PARAM\r\n - from OMMCommon\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n"}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a check before your add function call, to see if @CurrentClicks has a value. If a null value is passed, the add function will not evaluate. You need to change your code to something like this below:

```
if(NOT EMPTY(@CurrentClicks)) then  
Set @UpdateClicks = Add(@CurrentClicks, 1)
endif
```

The _subscriberkey works in email. To pass subscriber key for use in the cloud page, you need to pass it in the url and then fetch it using [request parameter](https://ampscript.guide/requestparameter/)

Comment: It's not true. The attribute ("Collectors") has default value equals 0 and nullable is unchecked

Comment: Yes, that is correct, but you are doing a lookup based on subscriber key, if there is no record for your subscriber in the DE, then @CurrentClicks will return null value.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I have thought. I couldn't retrieve _subscriberkey at that moment but now it seems okay (maybe server went error). How to identify a contact on Cloudpage without using "_subscriberkey "? Do you have any idea how to do it?

Comment: I edited my answer above :)